# Let X and Y be in independent standard normal random variables, and define a new RV by U = .6X + .8Y. a) Determine Corr(X, U).

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have tried determining $Corr(X,U) = \frac{Cov(X,U)}{\sigma_X \sigma_U} $

$Cov(X, 0.6X + 0.8Y) = Cov(X,0.6X) + Cov(X,0.8Y)$

Since X,Y are independent variable $Cov(X,0.8Y) = 0$

$Cov(X,0.6X) = 0.6Cov(X,X)$

 Hence 
$Cov(X,U) = 0.6 $

${\sigma_u}^2  = 0.6^2{\sigma_x}^2  + 0.8^2{\sigma_y}^2 $

Now i am having difficulty simplifying the answer specifically the $\sigma_u$ term.
The solution simplifies to $Corr(X,U) = 0.6Corr(X,X) + 0.8Corr(X,Y)$

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> The solution simplifies to $\operatorname{Corr}(X, U) = 0.6 \operatorname{Corr}(X, X) + 0.8 \operatorname{Corr}(X, Y)$

but note that *this* can also simplify quite a bit, since $\operatorname{Corr}(X, X) = 1$ for any random variable (write down the definition to see why), and $\operatorname{Corr}(X, Y) = 0$ by independence. Hence, that answer simplifies to just $0.6$.

As for simplifying your answer: since $X, Y$ are standard normal variables, note that $\sigma_x = \sigma_y = 1$, whence your expression for $\sigma_u^2$ becomes

$$\sigma_u^2 = 0.6^2 \cdot 1 + 0.8^2 \cdot 1 = 1$$

which gives the desired result.